# How to change webview color at time of loading URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, webview

In my app,

I open a url in webview,

But it takes some time to open a url in webview,

Within that time webview shows white background,

I want to change that background.

I  try with

```
 webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
```

It"s not work for me

So,How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while create

```
 [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
 [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
 [webView setOpaque:NO];


 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

    [webView setOpaque:YES];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];



 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];

}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];

}
```